Ubuntu Error in 'sudo apt update' ROS installation
I'm getting this error when trying to install ROS Noetic. I've tried quite a few fixes on this website, but none work. Would appreciate it if someone looked over and suggested fixes:
sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu noble InRelease 
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease 
Err: 3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu noble Release
404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


Looks like the developers of ROS did not make Noetic available on Ubuntu 24.04
